# How to auto instrument my Spring Boot web api call tracing and send to Google Cloud Trace

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, trace

I am trying to figure out how to auto instrument my Spring Boot web api call tracing to Google Cloud Trace. (My Spring Boot app is in GKE).

I did similar thing for my Node service, which could use OpenTememetry js package auto instrument express calls and use Google Cloud Trace exporter.

But for my Spring Boot app, I tried a few ways, but I guess due to lack of knowledge I am not able to achieve what I want.

1. I try to use OpenTelemetry java lib, it mentioned it can auto instrument spring boot, but I don't know how to achieve it and I didn't find an export to Google Cloud Trace(stackdriver) neither
2. I try to use OpenCensus, It has a Google Cloud Trace export, but I didn't see any document mentioned how to auto instrument spring boot.
3. I try to use OpenTelmetry and instead of use an export, I deployed an OpenTelemtry Collector, but I don't know how the config the collector and the SDK to let the auto instrumented tracing spans got to the OpenTelemetry collector.

Does anyone has experiences using OpenCensus/OpenTelemetry to generate tracing information and forward it to Google Cloud Trace(StackDrivers).

Comment: Have you seen this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/java)? It discusses how to set up cloud trace for java. Perhaps it might be of help. Also, take a look at [this] which is a Github page on openCensus quick start for [Java libraries](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-java) and it may be of help.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to work out some final solution?

Answer (score 0):

take a look of this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-java/blob/main/exporters/auto/README.md), you will have to use an otel extension and set the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env vars